# How to convert Grid North & Grid East into latitude and longitude?

Tags: coordinate-system

We have grid north and grid east data that we have received for address information. How can this be converted into latitude and longitude? I am not sure what format this grid_east and grid_north data is in, but it seems to uniquily identify a record. The numbers are integers. (large)

Here are some examples: (They are in Upstate New York)

6 HERON WAY NORTH 14450 GRID EAST: 803160 GRID NORTH: 1122110

16 CROSSWINDS CIR 14450 GRID EAST: 819252 GRID NORTH: 1123388

Comment: Examples of the numbers and where the are roughly located (if you know that) would be helpful.

Comment: There are *thousands* of different systems out there (see http://spatialreference.org/). Since this is a detective task, you need to look at the evidence to narrow down the search. What region the coordinates are from. Are the measures in metres or feet. etc.

Comment: I have added some examples (they are in a spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely they are a State Plane coordinate system for your local New York area.  Check the units (Ft, meters?), Google coordinate systems for your area/state, once you're sure of the system there are many ways to re-project them or convert systems.

Answer (score -3):

Use QGIS and export the data to a new projection, WGS84 would be the choice. 2 minute job.

Comment: that assumes that QGIS can work out the projection.

Comment: ouch!                 I was sorta tryin to encourage chris to try..... Now that he has provided examples, it is a very different question